# How to pass looping value as a collective array and insert once

Tags: php, arrays

I'm passing foreach value into a function to get inserted into the database. WHta its doing now is, instead of storing multiple values for one ID , it creates one ID for each value.

For example:

I have an array rate[10,20,30,70,200].

Now when I pass this array to a function that responsible for inserting these values, I expect one id to be created to store all these values.
like:

```
Id(column):1 Day_1(column):10 Day_3(column):20 Day_7(column):30 Day_15(column):70 Day_30(column):200.
```

But it storing like this:

Id(column):1 Day_1(column):10 Day_3(column):10 Day_7(column):10 Day_15(column):10 Day_30(column):10.

Id(column):2 Day_1(column):20 Day_3(column):20 Day_7(column):20 Day_15(column):20 Day_30(column):20.

and so forth...

This is how I'm passing the value:

```
$rate=$data["rate"];
foreach($rate as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key."->";
    echo $value;
    $car->rate = $value;
    $car->rentalRate();
}
```

And this is how the function capture the value and inserts multiple time:

```
public function rentalRate($rate = NULL)

{
    $rate = $rate == NULL ? $this->rate : $rate;
    echo "Rate inserted!";
    $this->generateReport();
    echo $rate;
    $sql="INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES('{$rate}','{$rate}', '{$rate}','{$rate}','{$rate}')";
    $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I tried this way where I pass the rate array itself to the function

```
$rate=$data["rate"];//array rate[10,20,40,60,80]
$car->rate = $rate;//assigning the variable in the function with array value
$car->rentalRate();//calling the function
```

//And in the function,

```
 public function rentalRate($rate = NULL)
        {
            $rate=array();
            $rate = $rate == NULL ? $this->rate : $rate;
            echo "Rate inserted!";
            $this->generateReport();
            echo $rate;

            $sql="INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES('{$rate[0]}','{$rate[1]}', '{$rate[2]}','{$rate[3]}','{$rate[4]}')";
            $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

This inserts only one record and I wanted but the value are 0. Maybe can someone tell me how to get the rate array value and insert into the table? I'm afraid if I use foreach here, it will still inserts multiple records for each value..

my full function

```
<?php
interface db
{
    public static function addConnection();
}
interface rental
{
    public function addCar();
    public function rentalRate();

}
abstract class report
{
    public function generateReport()
    {
        echo "All done.Now generate report.";
    }
}

class connection implements db 
{
    public static $servername = "localhost";
    public static $username = "root";
    public static $password = "";
    public static $dbname = "carrental";
    public static $port="3306";
    public static $pdo;

    public static function addConnection()
    {
      try 
      {
          self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=carrental", self::$username, self::$password);
          self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      } catch(PDOException $e)
      {
          echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }

      self::$pdo->query("use carrental");

    }
}

class car extends report implements rental
{
    public $name;
    public $maker;
    public $type;
    public $colour;
    public $passanger;
    public $rate;

    public function __construct($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4,$param5,$param6)
    {
        $this->name=$param1;
        $this->maker=$param2;
        $this->type=$param3;
        $this->colour=$param4;
        $this->passanger=$param5;
        $this->rate=$param6;
        connection::addConnection();
    }
    public function addCar()
    {

        $sql="INSERT INTO car(car_name,car_maker,car_type,car_colour,num_passanger)VALUES('{$this->name}','{$this->maker}', '{$this->type}','{$this->colour}','{$this->passanger}')";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Data inserted!";
        //$this->rentalRate();
    }
    public function rentalRate($rate = NULL)
    {
        $rate=array();
        $rate = $rate == NULL ? $this->rate : $rate;
        echo "Rate inserted!";
        $this->generateReport();
        echo $rate;

        $sql="INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES('{$rate[0]}','{$rate[1]}', '{$rate[2]}','{$rate[3]}','{$rate[4]}')";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

//$car1=new car("Honda Accord","Honda","5 wheeler","Red",10);
//$car1->addCar();
//$car1->generateReport();

?>
```

Comment: `{$rate}','{$rate}', '{$rate}','{$rate}','{$rate}` - what did you exepct? You're using the same value/parameter over and over again. First step: pass all the parameters you need for the INSERT query to rentalRate()

Comment: From where are you getting this one `$this->rate` `$this->generateReport();`

Comment: "From where are you getting this one"  - From ` $car->rate = $value;`

Comment: @Uchiha, I added y full code, from there you can find where I got the above two from..

Comment: `echo "Rate inserted!";` - a bit premature, isn't it?

Comment: You "full code" is quite different on an import part - `VALUES('{$rate[0]}','{$rate[1]}', '{$rate[2]}','{$rate[3]}','{$rate[4]}')`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rentalRate($rate = NULL)
{
    $rate = (NULL===$rate) ? $this->rate : $rate;
    if ( !is_array($rate) || 5!=count($rate) ) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$rate must be an array of five elements');
    }

    // since you already use prepare() make use of the placeholder/parameter functionality
    $sql='INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)';
    // hopefully the error mode has been set to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ?
    // otherwise error handling code is required here
    $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    // same here: expections or error handling is required
    $stmt->execute($rate);
}
```

and then forget about the foreach loop and just call `$car->rentalRate($data["rate"]);`

Comment: $data["rate"] is an array; So how can I pass that to the function and what will be inserted in the VALUES?

Comment: "So how can I pass that to the function" - you just do, like any other variable/parameter, `$car->rentalRate($data["rate"])`. "what will be inserted in the VALUES" - see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php